# How Do I Document Packages in Java?

Tags: java, package, javadoc

In the Java APIs I can see Javadoc comments for packages.

How/where do I place Javadoc comments to document a package?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

As of 1.5 you can define a `package-info.java` file and provide a standard javadoc style comment for a package:

com/foo/package-info.java:

```
/**
 * com.foo is a group of bar utils for operating on foo things.
 */
package com.foo;

//rest of the file is empty
```

[Language specification for packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1)

Comment: Direct link to spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1

Comment: in intellij you can right click on a package and the option to create this should be under the new file menu

Comment: I found the file needed to be in packagename/src/packagename (with the rest of the source files)

Answer (score 56):

Up to and including Java 1.4, you had to provide a HTML file package.html, as described in the other answers.

Since Java 1.5 you can also provide a `package-info.java`, which contains a regular Javadoc comment (no HTML). The latter is preferred, as it gives you some extra features (notably package annotations).

Details:
[Sun's docs for javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment)

Comment: +1 for mentioning both ways, and the essential difference between them. By the way, at least IntelliJ IDEA currently has better support for package.html (Ctrl-Q on a package name shows the package Javadocs).

Comment: Update to my previous comment: nowadays IDEA supports `package-info.java` just fine.

Answer (score 3):

With a `package.html` file at the package level (i.e. in the directory for that package). This should be a fully-formed `HTML` file, with the `<html>` tag defined in it

Comment: More details?  What should the file look like?

Comment: It's an HTML file containing the description of your package. That's it!

Comment: This is the old way to do it.  From Java 1.5 onwards you can use package-info.java