# Empty template for package-level Javadoc file

Tags: java, javadoc

The Oracle page "[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#packagecomments)" has a link to a "[Empty Template for Package-Level Doc Comment File](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/package-template-135098.html)" which does not show the expected content of a basic 'package.html' file. I am maintaining old Javadoc and it would be interesting to see a correct example of package.html and overview.html.

Is there a getting started with (classic) Javadoc page which shows the correct content of these files?

Comment: So, looks like it got forgotten when they converted the documentation to the new format :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer you want is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624422/how-do-i-document-packages-in-java).

The new `package-info.java` is a better way do document a package.